# Cannot create a project using appcelerator through CLI or Appcelerator Studio

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-studio

When I try to create a project either through the appc new command, or through the Appcelerator Studio I get an error. I have tried to uninstall and reinstall Appcelerator Studio a couple of times, but the errors do not change. The appc output is below, the error from the studio is the same:

```
[INFO]  Creating app project
[INFO]  Template directory: /Users/<user>/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/8.1.0.GA/templates/app/default
[INFO]  Writing tiapp.xml
[INFO]  Project created successfully in 163ms
An uncaught exception was thrown!
Unexpected end of JSON input
Unexpected end of JSON input
```

Comment: any solution you got ? same problem for me

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 4):

Please make sure you have the latest Appcelerator CLI installed using
`npm i -g appcelerator`

Alternatively, you can build via the Titanium Open Source CLI. You can install it with `npm i -g titanium` and run the app via `ti build p ios|android`.